# Force the correct font-size in Blackberry for rendering in an HTML email?

Tags: email, mobile, blackberry, html-email, font-size

I'm working on an html email that needs to render well on the Blackberry OS. The formatting of the text keeps getting blown up in Blackberry, see screenshots.

Blackberry ------------ Correct ------------

[image: Blackberry Screenshot]
[image: Correct Screenshot]

Here is my current code -

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" style="background-color:#000000 !important;padding:0;" bgcolor="#000000">
 <tr>
  <td style="color:#ffffff;font-size:12px;background-color:#000000;" bgcolor="#000000" valign="top">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:22px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:24px;">
       Aliquam Commodo Velit vel Ipsum
    </span>
    <span style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:13px;">
       <br>
    </span>
    Duis consectetur velit vel ipsum interdum anella onsequat lacus mattis.        
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. This is wracking my brain. Thanks!

Comment: I have also now tried `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-moz-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;text-size-adjust:none;` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this did it for me:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
      * { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
}
```

Comment: While that fix didn't specifically work for me, it did lead me down the right path.

`@media (max-width: 800px) {* td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important; }}`

Comment: Hey, while this works great on BB OS7, I'm finding it makes the text really small on OS6. Have you seen something similar?

Comment: Right now I've only sent it through Email on Acid, tests should soon be hitting my testers' inboxes so I'll update if there are complaints.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up (sorry for the delay) and say it was approved by our testing team without changes.

Comment: Ok thanks for following up! Pretty weird that I've got this small text issue on BB6.

Comment: Done better with `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;` versus `none`. Testing on EOA we saw cases where just changing this on a 9930 would make the difference from a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

try adding min-width='600px' to the table, as some devices dont like widths in % (eg. Androids). Also, note the `font-size=12px` is applied to both the `<span>` as its applied to the `<td>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying here. The width is just a hypothetical. The Blackberry is ignoring both `font-size`s, and displaying them at some other size. It is also ignoring the `line-height`, but that is another matter.

Comment: when the widths of the devices are adjusted, the font-size seem to adjust automatically. I haven't worked on Blackberry, but from my experience with Androids, Apple products, you may want to remove `width` from `<table>` and add `min-width='600px'` to the `<body>`. Also, if you want to render the email on desktops as well, use media queries http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: I have never had this experience with Andorid or iOS devices. `min-width` is frequently ignored and will break the media-queries that I am already using. I only care about the `font-size` in this situation.

Comment: so you're using media query for the css for blackberry? if so, can you show that pls?

Comment: Blackberry is ignoring the media-query in its entirety, so it is irrelevant for the `font-size` issue.

Comment: can you show the media-query, to figure out why blackberry is ignoring it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have provided all that I am able to provide. Do you have an example of a media query that works on a Blackberry email? I have been unable to find any information addressing responsive email design specific to Blackberry. Everything says to provide a text version.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that the `font-size:22px` is overriding the `font-size:12px` given in `td`. What you can do is that instead of span divide your `td` into two td's and let them have the different font-sizes' html emails get the font from the `td` and not `span` tags.

Comment: Nope, put them in their own `td`s and it looks exactly the same.

`<tr>
<td style="color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;font-size:22px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:24px;background-color:#000000;" bgcolor="#000000" valign="top">
       Aliquam Commodo Velit vel Ipsum
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="color:#ffffff;font-size:12px;background-color:#000000;" bgcolor="#000000" valign="top">
    Duis consectetur velit vel ipsum interdum anella onsequat lacus mattis.        
  </td>
 </tr>`