# Media Queries for HTML Mailers

Tags: blackberry, media-queries, html-email

I have designed a responsive html mailer using media queries.

The media queries work very nicely for Iphone - but, they done seem to be working on Blackberry?

The media query I have used is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 551px)
```

Has anyone successfully designed a responsive HTML mailer that renders properly on blackberry?

looking forward to the responses.

Answer (score 2):

Blackberrys don't support them. Sorry.

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/media_queries_in_html_emails

Comment: so there is absolutely no scope for responsive design with BB?

Comment: For emails I'd steer well clear. The fact that tables are still the best way of getting good x email client consistency should tell you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found that Blackberry will accept media queries but only at the desktop size.

I used the following code, but only to keep the font from breaking the desktop layout on a Blackberry -

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {* td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important; }}
```

There is a potential issue with BBOS6 displaying text too small.

See: [Force the correct font-size in Blackberry for rendering in an HTML email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372898/force-the-correct-font-size-in-blackberry-for-rendering-in-an-html-email)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do when optimizing a site to support BlackBerry devices is download and install the official BlackBerry Device Simulator and BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulator Package.