# bb and windows or microsoft equivalent to ios webkit

Tags: blackberry, html-email

Can you please advise – certain code to be added to stop blackberry devices changes the font size, it might be a bb equivalent of ios -webkit-text-size-adjust?
Blackberry:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/resultcaptures/bbf72760-1234-4efa-9e57-647b723624d1.fullpage.png

same here the

tag font size is supposed 11px – a windows or Microsoft equivalent of ios -webkit-text-size-adjust
HTC Windows 7.5
https://s3.amazonaws.com/resultcaptures/c0076514-4f30-47a2-9603-07474f5a3c4d.fullpage.png

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {* td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important; }}
```

[Force the correct font-size in Blackberry for rendering in an HTML email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372898/force-the-correct-font-size-in-blackberry-for-rendering-in-an-html-email)